# Java Recursive function with two for loops in it

Tags: java, recursion

Inside my program, the most important part is filling an array with some number of objects.

These objects are bishops on a chess board. There are alternative functions to place the bishop and the place it attacked places or decide if the board is filled properly are made.

At the end of the first couple of loops the board is filled and falls back into its previous state where the next attempt is done.

The problem is that somehow it uses not the old array but the last one so that the array keeps piling up numbers in stead of making all the possible options. What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
Think i have to mention that in the outcome the two is how they are should be. after that this one is counted with no zero in it and CheckGoedeStand returns a one.

```
    int SolveBoard(int m,int n,int d,int l) {
        int[][] field = new int[m][n]; // this is the m*n schaakbord. int is standaard 0.
        // probleem opgelost
        System.out.println("aantal lopers: " + l);
        int GoedeStand = Recursie(field,0,0, m, n, d, l);
        PrintFieldImage(field);
        return GoedeStand;  
    }

    //deze fuctie is alleen gekoppeld saan SolveBoard()
    int Recursie(int[][] field, int LopersSet, int AGB, int m, int n, int d, int l) {
        int mcount, ncount;
        int[][] fieldC = field;
        //de rekenlus              
        // 0 is leeg, 1 is aangevallen, 2 is lopers plaats, 3 is dame haar plaats      
        if (LopersSet < l) {
            LopersSet++;
            for (mcount = 0; mcount < m; mcount++) {
                for (ncount = 0; ncount < n; ncount++) {
                    //if (field[mcount][ncount] <= 1) {
                        fieldC = PlaatsLoper(fieldC, m, n, mcount, ncount);
                        //nu de recursie, eerst kopie maken van bord zodat deze niet verloren gaat
                        AGB = Recursie(fieldC, LopersSet, AGB, m, n, d, l);
                    //}
                }
            }
        } else {
            PrintFieldImage(field);
        }
        if (CheckGoedeStand(field, m, n) == 1 && LopersSet == l) {
            //PrintFieldImage(field);
            AGB++;
            //field = new int[m][n];
        }
        return AGB;
    }
```

As you can see, I start with an empty array, d is unused, and for the testing I have m, n, and l set as 2.

This is my output:

```
[2, 0]
[0, 1]

[2, 2]
[1, 1]

[2, 2]
[2, 1]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]

[2, 2]
[2, 2]
AGB= 19
```

Comment: Think i have to mention that in the outcome the two is how they are should be. after that this one is counted with no zero in it and CheckGoedeStand returns a one.

Comment: What language are the comments in the code in?

Comment: Sorry for the unusable comments. They are Dutch.

Comment: It's fine; Google Translate provides.